# Viewport sets size to desktop browser

Tags: html, css, viewport

To make the website look good on mobile device also i used

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=true width=320px">
```

but the above code shrikes and zooms out the size to 67% on desktop site aswell

do i have to add multiple code to make that restrain from happening

Comment: Try using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` instead. Let me know if it works

Comment: I use `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`, I removed `content="width=device-width"` because it doesn't allow full width on iPhone 5 and up because of the larger screen.